# Excel VBA filter multiple sheets on name and save as a seperate file

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a report with 4 worksheets: 1 frontpage and 3 worksheets that have to be filtered on a name. Once filtered, the sheets have to be saved as a seperate file.

I am using the following code now (see below), but I have some questions:

1. How do I remove the data that does not meet the criteria? So when the data is filtered on Name1, all other Names should be removed.
2. How do I copy the frontpage (sheet1) together with the 3 filtered sheets into 1 file? It now only copies the 3 filtered sheets. The frontpage does not need to be filtered.
3. How do I paste the data as values (it's pasted as formula now)?

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFilters()
Dim sheetsToFilter As Variant, sheetName As Variant
Dim sheetsColumnToFilterOn As Variant
Dim criteria As Variant, criterium As Variant
Dim iSht As Long
Dim pre As String

sheetsToFilter = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")
sheetsColumnToFilterOn = Array(2, 3, 4)
criteria = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")

pre = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each criterium In criteria
    For iSht = LBound(sheetsToFilter) To UBound(sheetsToFilter)
        Call Autofilter(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetsToFilter(iSht)).Range("A1"), CLng(sheetsColumnToFilterOn(iSht)), CStr(criterium))
    Next iSht

    Call CopySheet(sheetsToFilter, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & criterium & " " & pre & ".xlsx")
Next criterium

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub Autofilter(rng As Range, col As Long, criteria As String)

With rng
    .Autofilter
    .Autofilter field:=col, Criteria1:=criteria & "*", VisibleDropDown:=True
End With

End Sub


Sub CopySheet(sheetsToFilter As Variant, shtName As String)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetsToFilter).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=shtName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On q.3 A simple way to remove the formulas from a sheet, but retain the formatting on the current sheet is `ActiveSheet.UsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value`

Comment: I'd use a separate 'control' Worbook. Write a macro that opens the master sheet, saves it as a new filename with xlWorkbookDefault, and then work on the copy, deleting rows according to whatever filter you want. Then repeat for the other workbooks. That is probably easier than copying individual sheets or data. Does depend a bit on filesize.

Answer (score 0):

### Backup Worksheets

1. `"<>" & Criteria(n) & "*"`
2. `swb.Worksheets(Array(wsNames(0), wsNames(n))).Copy`
3. `rg.Value = rg.Value`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateBackups()
    
    Const wsNamesList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4"
    Const CriteriaList As String = ",Name1,Name2,Name3"
    
    Dim fFields As Variant: fFields = VBA.Array(, 2, 3, 4)
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    
    Dim dStamp As String: dStamp = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = swb.Path
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim drg As Range ' Delete Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(wsNames) ' 0 is front sheet
        swb.Worksheets(Array(wsNames(0), wsNames(n))).Copy
        Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = dwb.Worksheets(wsNames(n))
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rg.Value = rg.Value
        rg.AutoFilter fFields(n), "<>" & Criteria(n) & "*"
        Set drg = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, fFields(n) - 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & "\" & Criteria(n) & " " & dStamp & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without alerts
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlWorkbookDefault
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close
    Next n

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MsgBox "Today's worksheet backups created.", vbInformation, "Backup"

End Sub
```